# MySQL: how can I count number of articles by a join table

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a table with news items, I have another table with `media_types`, I want to make one simple query that reads the `media_types` table and count for each record how many `news_items` exist.

The result will be turned into a json response that I will use for a chart, this is my SQLstatement

```sql
SELECT
  gc.country AS "country"
, COUNT(*) AS "online"
FROM default_news_items AS ni
JOIN default_news_item_country AS nic ON (nic.id = ni.country)
JOIN default_country AS c ON (nic.country = c.id)
JOIN default_geo_country AS gc ON (gc.id = c.geo_country)
LEFT JOIN default_medias ON (m.id = ni.media)
WHERE TRUE
  AND ni.deleted = 0
  AND ni.date_item > '2013-10-23'
  AND ni.date_item < '2013-10-29'
AND gc.country <> 'unknown'
AND m.media_type = '14'
GROUP BY gc.country
ORDER BY `online` desc LIMIT 10
```

This is the json respond I create from the mysql respond

```
   [
     {"country":"New Zealand","online":"7"},
     {"country":"Switzerland","online":"1"}
   ]
```

How do I add print and social data to my output like this

I would like the json respond look like this

```
   [
     {"country":"New Zealand","online":"7", "social":"17", "print":"2"},
     {"country":"Switzerland","online":"1", "social":"7", "print":"1"}
   ]
```

Can I use the `count (*)` in the select statement to do something like this

```
COUNT( * ) as online, COUNT( * ) as social, COUNT( * ) as print
```

Is it possible or do I have to do several SQL statement to get the data I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This is the general structure:

```
SELECT default_geo_country.country as country,
       SUM(default_medias.media_type = 14) as online,
       SUM(default_medias.media_type = XX) as social,
       SUM(default_medias.media_type = YY) as print
FROM ...
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation.  Your question, however, only shows the online media type.

Your query would be more readable by using table aliases and removing the back quotes.  Also, if `media_type` is an integer, then you should not enclose the constant for comparison in single quotes -- I, for one, find it misleading to compare a string constant to an integer column.

I suspect this is the way you want to go.  Where the `. . .` is, you want to fill in with the counts for the other media types.

```
SELECT default_geo_country.country as country,
       sum(media_type = '14') as online,           
       sum(default_medias.media_type = XX) as social,
       sum(default_medias.media_type = YY) as print
       . . . 
FROM default_news_items ni JOIN
     default_news_item_country nic
     ON nic.id = ni.country JOIN
     default_country dc 
     ON nic.country = dc.id JOIN
     default_geo_country gc
     ON gc.id = dc.geo_country LEFT JOIN
     default_medias dm
     ON dm.id = dni.media
WHERE ni.deleted = '0' 
 AND ni.date_item > '2013-10-23' 
 AND ni.date_item < '2013-10-29' 
 AND gc.country <> 'unknown' 
GROUP BY gc.country
ORDER BY online desc
LIMIT 10
```